# MySQL multiple joins to same table

Tags: mysql, join

I am attempting to improve the performance of a program that tracks the most popular paths taken through a website. a given URL is registered in table sessionpage with a unique_id:

```
+-----------+--------------------------+---------------------+
| unique_id | page_url                 | mod_date_stamp      |
+-----------+--------------------------+---------------------+
|      2378 | /resources/series75.html | 2008-10-03 22:49:00 |
+-----------+--------------------------+---------------------+
```

Then another table, session, counts the number of hits for a set of up to 5 urls using the unique_id from sessionpage.

session

```
+-----------+---------+-----------------+-----------+---------------------+-------
| unique_id | counter | sequence_length | yearmonth | mod_date_stamp      | page1 | 
+-----------+---------+-----------------+-----------+---------------------+-------
|         1 |       2 |               2 |    201203 | 2012-03-28 15:42:38 |  5298 |  
+-----------+---------+-----------------+-----------+---------------------+-------

+-------+-------+-------+-------+
page2 | page3 | page4 | page5 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
6075 |     0 |     0 |     0 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Right now, the stats program is fetching the unique_id from session page for each URL, which is taking way too long. I want to join sessionpage back to session multiple times so that the page1 - page5 fields show the url path (or 0/null) rather than the unique_id from sessionpage to speed up the program.

The end result should look like:

```
+-----------+---------+-----------------+-----------+---------------------+-------
| unique_id | counter | sequence_length | yearmonth | mod_date_stamp      | page1 | 
+-----------+---------+-----------------+-----------+---------------------+-------
|         1 |       2 |               2 |    201203 | 2012-03-28 15:42:38 |  /path/index.html |  
+-----------+---------+-----------------+-----------+---------------------+-------

+-------+-------+-------+-------+
page2            | page3 | page4 | page5 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
/path3/disk.html |     0 |     0 |     0 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there an index on unique_id on the second table?

Comment: No, but there could be. Currently, unique_id is the primary key on session. Each combination of possible URLs has its own unique_id.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to join multiple times. It seems the way your table structure is that you'd get all the information with one join. Multiple joins won't help performance. Please clarify what you want your end result to look like.

Comment: Erica - so you're saying that the unique_id is not unique to the URL in your sessionpage table? (in other words you have the same URL under multiple IDs in that table)

Comment: I updated the post to give more clarity. The sessionpage unique_id is unique (each id maps to only one URL, and each URL has only one id). unique_id shows up multiple times in session, under (one or more of) page1, page2, page3, page4, page5.

Comment: page1, page2 - page5 are the foreign keys that refers to a sessionpage row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment that page1, page2.. are foreign keys columns, I think it's simple.

Something like:

```
SELECT 
    s.unique_id, s.counter, s.sequence_length, s.yearmonth, 
    s.mod_date_stamp,
    pg1.page_url as page1, pg2.page_url as page2, 
    pg3.page_url as page3, pg4.page_url as page4, 
    pg5.page_url as page5
FROM 
    session s
LEFT JOIN 
    sessionpage pg1 ON pg1.unique_id = s.page1 
LEFT JOIN 
    sessionpage pg2 ON pg2.unique_id = s.page2
LEFT JOIN 
    sessionpage pg3 ON pg3.unique_id = s.page3
LEFT JOIN 
    sessionpage pg4 ON pg4.unique_id = s.page4
LEFT JOIN 
    sessionpage pg5 ON pg5.unique_id = s.page5
```

I think this will work.

But when there is no value on column (on table session), you should use null instead of 0 (zero).

Another tip, on the SELECT statement, if you don't want NULL values you can use:

```
COALESCE(pg5.page_url, ' ') as page5
```