# MySQL join and subquery from the join

Tags: sql, join, subquery

This is a followup to [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916331/mysql-multiple-joins-to-same-table):

```
SELECT s.unique_id, s.counter, s.sequence_length, s.yearmonth, s.mod_date_stamp,
  pg1.page_url as page1, pg2.page_url as page2, pg3.page_url as page3,
  pg4.page_url as page4, pg5.page_url as page5
FROM session s
  LEFT JOIN sessionpage pg1 ON pg1.unique_id = s.page1 
  LEFT JOIN sessionpage pg2 ON pg2.unique_id = s.page2
  LEFT JOIN sessionpage pg3 ON pg3.unique_id = s.page3
  LEFT JOIN sessionpage pg4 ON pg4.unique_id = s.page4
  LEFT JOIN sessionpage pg5 ON pg5.unique_id = s.page5
```

works fine to display the entire table. Now, I need to `select s.unique_id WHERE page1=/path/to/something.html AND page2=/path/to/somethingelse.html`.

I can't figure out how to return only the `unique_id` without returning the whole table. I know I need a nested query, but I can't figure out the syntax.

It should look something like:

```
SELECT s.unique_id 
  (SELECT pg1.page_url as page1, pg2.page_url as page2, pg3.page_url as page3,
    pg4.page_url as page4, pg5.page_url as page5 FROM session201203) s
  LEFT JOIN sessionpage pg1 ON pg1.unique_id = s.page1 
  LEFT JOIN sessionpage pg2 ON pg2.unique_id = s.page2 
  LEFT JOIN sessionpage pg3 ON pg3.unique_id = s.page3 
  LEFT JOIN sessionpage pg4 ON pg4.unique_id = s.page4 
  LEFT JOIN sessionpage pg5 ON pg5.unique_id = s.page5
WHERE s.sequence_length = 2 AND s.page1 = '/path1.html' AND s.page2 = '/path2.html';
```

But this query fails because it tries to find pg1 etc before it has been joined. I've tried a bunch of things and can't figure it out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: move the bracket `) s` after the last join

```
SELECT s.unique_id 
  FROM (SELECT pg1.page_url as page1, pg2.page_url as page2, pg3.page_url as page3,
    pg4.page_url as page4, pg5.page_url as page5 FROM session201203
  LEFT JOIN sessionpage pg1 ON pg1.unique_id = s.page1 
  LEFT JOIN sessionpage pg2 ON pg2.unique_id = s.page2 
  LEFT JOIN sessionpage pg3 ON pg3.unique_id = s.page3 
  LEFT JOIN sessionpage pg4 ON pg4.unique_id = s.page4 
  LEFT JOIN sessionpage pg5 ON pg5.unique_id = s.page5) s
WHERE s.sequence_length = 2 AND s.page1 = '/path1.html' AND s.page2 = '/path2.html';
```

Comment: Got it! This was the final syntax:

`SELECT q.unique_id 
  FROM (SELECT s.unique_id, pg1.page_url as page1, pg2.page_url as page2, pg3.page_url as page3,
    pg4.page_url as page4, pg5.page_url as page5 FROM session201203 AS s
  LEFT JOIN sessionpage pg1 ON pg1.unique_id = s.page1 
  LEFT JOIN sessionpage pg2 ON pg2.unique_id = s.page2 
  LEFT JOIN sessionpage pg3 ON pg3.unique_id = s.page3 
  LEFT JOIN sessionpage pg4 ON pg4.unique_id = s.page4 
  LEFT JOIN sessionpage pg5 ON pg5.unique_id = s.page5) AS q
  WHERE s.page1 = '/path1.html' AND s.page2 = '/path2.html';`

Comment: Basically, your code worked except "s" needed to stick with the inner query and I assigned "q" as the outer query.